# Is "providing with Ukraine" grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, collocations

I heard John Kirby said this:

> “We have been, from the beginning of this war now 11 months ago, have
> been evolving the capabilities we’re providing with Ukraine, with the
> conditions on the ground,”

I know "provide with" is a natural combination of words but I am pretty sure this is not the case, I think he should have used "to" Could somebody please confirm?

Comment: Most people would probably prefer ***to***, but ***with, regarding, concerning*** are all at least "acceptable". And imho they all carry a shade less "commitment" than the default preposition. It's not something to fret about, though

Comment: @FumbleFingers   Thank you! Did you forget to put the "of" in a shade of less commitment?

Comment: Certainly not! Not that including "of" would be invalid - it would just never be my choice,

Answer (score 1):

The prepositional phrases starting with "with" are going with the verb *evolve,* not with the word *provide.*

In other words, we can rephrase it as:

> We are providing some capabilities. We have been evolving them with Ukraine, with conditions on the ground.

The first "with" means "alongside"; the second means "in accordance with."

Answer (score 1):

## 'provide Ukraine with' is best

Here are two alternative, normal-speech English versions of the longer phrase:

> ...the capabilities we're providing Ukraine *with*

> ...given we're providing Ukraine *with* these capabilities

This second example above shows what `with` would mean. While `with` is a preposition, prepositions can be used by themselves if the noun they accompany is unknown in a somewhat re-arranged sentence, meaning something like this...

> We're providing Ukraine with capabilities and *have been evolving the capabilities we’re **providing Ukraine with***.

In that example, `with` somewhat points to the previous `with`. Because we already know this, we don't need the part of the sentence before `and` in order for this to work. Hence `providing Ukraine with` is best.

This would use `to`:

> ...the capabilities we're providing *to* Ukraine

Note that `with` and `to` would both come from the [Dative](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Dative) [Noun Case](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases), if translating from Russian, Greek, German, Czech, et cetera. In English, the two prepositions are similar and often exchangeable, though not identical. So, the speech pattern from John Kirby might indicate a "speaking mistake made by someone with advanced English skill". If he was typing it out, he might have likely used `providing Ukraine with`.

I love this question!